# Using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement Namespaces, Why is the PartialManagementObject.StopMaintenanceMode function ignoring the endTime parameter

Tags: c#, .net, maintenance-mode

I'm using `PartialMonitoringObject.StopMaintenanceMode` to set maintenance modes on Microsoft System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb424491.aspx). No matter what I do, it seems to be ignoring the end time and ending my maintenance window immediately no matter what I specify. The code looks like this:

```
foreach (string SCOMServer in SCOMServers)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<PartialMonitoringObject> windowsComputerObjects;          
    ManagementGroup managementGroup;
    MonitoringClass windowsComputerClass;               
    managementGroup = new ManagementGroup(SCOMServer);           
    windowsComputerClass = managementGroup.GetMonitoringClass(SystemMonitoringClass.WindowsComputer);
    windowsComputerObjects = managementGroup.GetPartialMonitoringObjects(new MonitoringObjectGenericCriteria("Name='" + ServerFQDN + "'"), windowsComputerClass);


    foreach (PartialMonitoringObject windowsComputerObject in windowsComputerObjects)
    {
        if (windowsComputerObject.InMaintenanceMode)
        {
            windowsComputerObject.StopMaintenanceMode(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(DelayInMinutes),Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.TraversalDepth.Recursive);
            //  windowsComputerObject.ScheduleMaintenanceMode(DateTime.UtcNow,DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(DelayInMinutes)
            RetVal = true;
        }
    }

    `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the `StopMaintenanceMode` command doesn't work as documented, but changed the code to use `UpdateMaintenanceMode` instead, and it now does what I need it to do.

```
foreach (PartialMonitoringObject windowsComputerObject in windowsComputerObjects)
                {
                    if (windowsComputerObject.InMaintenanceMode)
                    {
                        if (DelayInMinutes == 0)
                        {
                            windowsComputerObject.StopMaintenanceMode(DateTime.UtcNow, Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.TraversalDepth.Recursive);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            windowsComputerObject.UpdateMaintenanceMode(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(DelayInMinutes), MaintenanceModeReason.PlannedOther, null, Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.TraversalDepth.Recursive);
                        }

                        RetVal = true;
                    }
                }
```

`